# Decomposing a "nonnegative" polynomial into a canonical form

Tags: polynomials

**EDIT:** This question is related to my research, but seemed too elementary to pose at MathOverflow, so I posted here.

If $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then $p(x) \ge 0$, $\forall x \ge 0$ if and only if $p(x) = \left([f_1(x)]^2 +[f_2(x)]^2\right) + x\left([g_1(x)]^2 + [g_2(x)]^2\right)$ (this result is known as the Pólya–Szegö theorem).

Consider the polynomial $p(x) = 4x^3 -2x+1$, whose graph is given by:
[image]

Clearly, $p(x) \ge 0$, $\forall x \ge 0$. Of course, this can be proven rigorously by showing that $p$ has a local minimum at $x = \sqrt{6}/6$. It seems that the only way to write $p$ in the canonical form above is $p(x) = x(4x^2 -2) + 1 = x\left((2x)^2 + (\sqrt{2}i)^2\right) + (1^2 + 0^2)$.

> **Question**: Is there a way to write $p$ in the canonical form above without complex numbers?

Comment: I don't believe the Polya's theorem uses complex coefficients (so the answer to your question is yes). Do you have a source for the theorem?

Comment: Indeed, hence my question. 

A reference: see Lemma 3.5 here: https://homepages.cwi.nl/~monique/files/moment-ima-update-new.pdf.

Comment: Right, Theorem 3.21's proof only uses real coefficients (Not explicitly stated in the theorem, but you can work through the proof with that restriction).  Though, applying that proof to your polynomial doesn't give us a "nice" expression, because the real root is "ugly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misconception seems to arise from thinking that the split of $ p(x) = (f_1 ^2 + f_2^2 ) + x (g_1 ^2 + g_2^2 ) $ is a split of even/odd degree, which is why you wrote

$$p (x) = x ( 4x^2 - 2 ) + 1 = \ldots $$

However, that need not be the case. For example, we could have

$$ p(x) = x ( 4x^2 - x) + (x^2 + 2x + 1) = \ldots $$

Here's a way to write it using only polynomials with real coefficients (though you really should give it a try by yourself first):

> $p(x) = x [ (2x-1)^2  + 1^2 ] + [(2x-1)^2 + 0^2 ] $

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I needed!